# OSX: MBP: How does system detect sd card inserted?

Tags: osx, devices, sd-card, mbr

I have a MacBookPro running Mavericks.  I can insert one sd card into the slot and it mounts just fine.  Another sd card I slip in and nothing happens.  It does not appear in disk utility.  It does not come up when I issue the mount command in Terminal.  But this same card goes into a Samsung Galaxy running android and it is detected, albeit saying it is either blank, or has a unrecognized filesystem.  So it got me to thinking...  how does OSX actually detect the physical plugging in of an sd card?  how does it treat it in the kernel? (is it a usb device?) how do I force the kernel and OS to see the physical device manually so that I can muck about with the most likely corrupted MBR?  Obviously this kind of process has to happen all the time, and I'm probably asking a lower level question than people usually try to answer.  And I'm getting confused searching the web for truly useful information and probably asking the wrong question the wrong way.

thanks

Comment: I run Linux on my MBP and `lsusb` reports `Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:8403 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader`. This should mean that the card reader is internally connected via the usb controller.

Comment: thanks I didn't know about lsusb, but have been thinking about adding a Linux

Answer (score 0):

Since posting I've continued digging and found several resources surrounding the issue and though I'd note them here.

on OSX if you have Xcode installed there are utilities that are useful in the /Dev*/App*/Util*/ directory... specifically USBProber.app and IORegistryExplorer.app
in USBProper there is a check box for "Probe suspended devices". once checked and a probe run my device popped up in DiskUtility.
through these I was able to find loads of info on the underlying structure of the entire system.

as for the recovery side of things...
clone whatever you are concerned with first, then work on the clone.

GNU ddrescue - great tool
http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/
search around and you can find precompiled binaries

TestDisk and Photorec - great tools
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: some discussions about this kind of problem:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=234401   
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1142030   
http://forums.steves-digicams.com/memory-cards-microdrives-card-readers/207072-recovering-bad-sd-card-my-experience-so-far.html#b   

Forensics Wiki -
http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Main_Page